# Pubnub multiuser chat

Tags: php, push-notification, chat, real-time, pubnub

I am developing a multi-user chatting system in php.
I know about push and pull, reverse ajax, comet etc. but mostly we have to configure over our server.

However, I can't access my server to install those scripts because I have shared hosting provider.

So after some research I came to know that **pusher**, **pubnub** provides api to have push data on browser.

The question is about **pubnub**, that they are providing channels to send data to clients, but problem is I want to develop multi-user chat in which the data will sent to only one user  not like multicasting chat.

As I think one solution is that to make a unique channel per user, so that data will only sent to that user, but this doesn't seems to be efficient. so any other way to implement multi-user chat system with **pubnub** ?

or any other suggestions that are better ?

Comment: You typically would create one channel for server to client comms, and another for client to client. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459123/pubnub-best-practice-how-to-manage-private-rooms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Multi-user Chat System with PubNub

Get Started - [PubNub best practice: How to manage private rooms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459123/pubnub-best-practice-how-to-manage-private-rooms?answertab=active#tab-top)

You are asking about a Multi-user Chat system with PubNub where the communication style is one-to-one between two users with parallel conversations.  Great news!  PubNub has a service called **PubNub PULSE** - provides One-to-One style communication ideal for your Multi-user Chat - http://www.pubnub.com/price (see **PULSE** section).

### PubNub Best Practice - How to manage Private Rooms

Also there is a conversation started here which Mikita mentioned on how to create Multiroom Chat Service, likely similar to Facebook Chat, where you are able to join and sit in on multiple chat rooms - [PubNub best practice: How to manage private rooms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459123/pubnub-best-practice-how-to-manage-private-rooms?answertab=active#tab-top)

> EDIT - UPDATED INFO - MARCH 2018

You use of one channel per user is not inefficient. Use as many channels as you like. They cost you nothing more (or less) with respect to how many channels you use.

The pricing plans mentioned above are obsolete. Please review the [PubNub Pricing and the Move Away from Device Counting.](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/pubnub-pricing-and-the-move-away-from-device-counting/)